# JTable in netbeans: how do display table of many columns

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a JTable of 25 columns, composed using the netbeans GUI builder.  I'd like for the GUI to display maybe 5 columns, and have a scrollbar for users to scroll through the remaining columns.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Screenshot attached shows 25 column table trying to be rendered to show all 25 columns (ugly mess).[image]

Comment: Alternate Solution: Make a "Unique Key" in the table and fetch all the related data related to that unique key.

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [`JTable#setAutoResizeMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode-int-)

In your case, you could use [`JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#AUTO_RESIZE_OFF)

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: A explaination with images would be great.

Comment: @AlitheDev Look at the linked tutorial - plenty of runnable examples